# some javascript functions don't work on iOS devices (iPhone, iPad)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, mouseover

hope you can help me. I'm freaking out after spending several days trying to solve this problem.

My JavaScript mouse event functions don't work on iOS devices. I red [this apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1) and i added to my html tags this attribute: `onclick="void(0)"` but it just doesn't want to work. i can trigger an alert message on any mouse events like this:

```
document.getElementById("el").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
alert("Bla-Bla");
)};
```

but stuff like this inside the same eventlistener is not being executed:

```
document.getElementById("el").classList.remove("bla-class");
```

does somebody maybe know if there is a solution for this problem?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console. in any desktop browser the code does work. only on iPad and iPhone doesn't

Comment: Probably unrelated but `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`.

Comment: it's not copy and pasted. was a typing mistake when i wrote this post. the code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the order of the brackets in your code, especially in the last line!
It should be like this:

```js
document.getElementById("el").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
  alert("Bla-Bla");
});
```

Comment: Nice catch :D, Not sure though if this was actually the reason, the site in question isn't online anymore, for ages. But thanx anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is probably not your code. The other thing that could cause this is that JavaScript might not be enabled for browsers in IOS, so you can try to go to Settings > Safari > Advanced >  JavaScript and then enable it.