# Parts of Javascript don't work, but only on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, htmlcollection

#### TL; DR

My HTML/CSS/JS web app works perfectly on all my Android devices and in my laptop browser, but not in Safari on iOS. Instead, the map doesn't load and click listeners don't get applied. It seems that the Javascript only partially loads, but that's ridiculous.

**Why does iOS Safari seem to load only half of my script?**

[See for yourself!](https://nronnei.github.io/projects/bss/) Check out the demo on my GitHub site.

I know this is a bad question by community guidelines, but I just don't know what question to ask. There are no console errors to follow up, no clues at all.

---

#### Background

I'm working on a little app I call Bike Share Explorer. It's a web app which uses Mapbox GL JS and Google MDL. This web map lets people explore bike share systems and bike availability in those systems.

#### The pieces

I'm using browserify to bundle Mapbox GL JS and other code I need with the Javascript for my page. The app is built to run on an Express server and the front is written using Pug, but whether I'm serving with Express or from the filesystem, everything works just fine on my computer.

#### What I've tried

Based on various SO posts and blogs, I've...

- Made sure that HTTP version 1.1 is used
- Made sure my headers contain `Content-Type: text/html`
- Set up CORS on my test server using [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) (really, I tried everything I could think of)
- Tried wrapping the body in a `<div onclick="void(0)">` ([see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143619/some-javascript-functions-dont-work-on-ios-devices-iphone-ipad))
- Tried changing the cursor to pointer (done on the body element)
- Tried using `touchstart` instead of `click`

I tested all of these methods using BrowserSync on several devices. All worked fine except the iPhone.

I then turned to a little debugging using `alert` to try and see which code was actually getting run. From that I can say that my script *is* being executed, and Mapbox GL JS says it *is* supported, but when I put the `alert` inside `map.on("load", () => {});` it's never fired on iOS Safari. If you visited the site on another device, you'll notice it *does* fire on that.

I wish I had a more specific question to ask, but I don't.

**Why does iOS Safari seem to load only half of my script?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, the page isn't working on iOS because an exception is being thrown

```
TypeError: btn of centerMapButtons is not a function. (In 'btn of centerMapButtons', 'btn of centerMapButtons' is undefined)
```

`centerMapButtons` does not implement an [iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterable) and therefore cannot be used in a `for...of` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. How did you find this exception, using Safari on a laptop? I couldn't get Chrome or Firefox to kick it out. My object is an `HTMLCollection`, so it wouldnt work with `for ... of` because it is an "array-like object", not an array?

Comment: There is a way to debug iOS safari on your desktop: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this later, [Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42958250/3888565) found the exception I couldn't see and ultimately led me to an answer.

`HTMLCollections` are array-like, but are not arrays. Therefore, you can't use `for ... of` on them (at least in Safari? It worked in Chrome and Firefox). Instead, you can do:

`const theElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("selected"));`

Or see [this article](https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9#.91pfjvyu0) for more explanation/options.